# Pass values of a submitted form to another controller in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple form as follows

```
<% provide(:title, 'View Mail') %>
  <h1>View Mail</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <%= form_tag('/mails/new') %> 
      <%= label_tag "Email Address" %><%= email_field_tag(:email) %><br>
      <%= label_tag "Password" %><%= password_field_tag(:password) %><br>
      <%= submit_tag "View my Mails" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What I actually want to do is capture the email and password field and forward them to another controller 'mails' so that I can use the value of email and password in that controller and then show the appropriate details.This is just a sample app for me to check something as I am new to rails.

What exactly should be in place of

```
<%= form_tag('/mails/new') %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% provide(:title, 'View Mail') %>
  <h1>View Mail</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <%= form_tag('/mails/new') do %> 
    <%= label :email %>
    <%= text_field :email) %><br>
    <%= label :password %>
    <%= password_field :password %><br>
    <%= submit_tag "View my Mails" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You need to define 'mails/new' path, in config/routes.db to be able to access that path.
Hopefully it answers your problem.

Comment: Thanks but I have mails/new defined already in routes.rb.The mails controller is where I want these values to be submitted so that the controller can pass these values to the function 'new' defined in the controller so that the view can be rendered.

Comment: I actually have a controller mails with a function 'new' and its path is already defined in routes.rb.In this function 'new' I have the following code where I need these values.     
    imap.login(config['username'], config['password'])

Comment: Hmm.. I don't really get it because I'm also newbie to Rails, but I'm sure this links (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-sessions_controller) can help you get through what you want. I suggest you use sessions to simplify sign in & out :) Good luck!

Comment: Well the reformatted code given by you was giving error so I reverted back to the original one..Thanks a lot for the link :-)